# Finding the text in PDF: Tm or Td/TD?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, pdf

I know that this question had already been asked a couple of times before, but I just want to clarify this. I have a pdf reader and I want to add a highlight function to it. I can already extract the text by parsing the `Tj` and `TJ` operators. Right now I want to find the location of the text in pdf.

At first I tried to find the `Tm` values. I was able to extract the (x,y) of the `Tm`, but it doesn't seem right. So I decided to go for the `Td` and `TD`. The problem is it seems like the pdf does not contain any `Td` or `TD` values, since the operator callbacks are never called. (I put a log in the callback just to see if it is being called, but it never showed up.)

So my question is if I want to find the position of the text in the pdf, which shall I look into? The `Tm` values or the `Td/TD` values? Or is it both?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:

Tm has six parameters: `a, b, c, d, e` and `f`. I know that `e` and `f` represents the `tx` and `ty`, but what does the other four parameters represent?

Comment: now stackoverflow users will help you even more :)

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith well can you help me my question?

Comment: Tm is a transformation matrix, and as such the first four parameters affect the scale, rotation and shear transforms. See section 4.2.2 on p204 of the PDF reference manual and section 4.2.3 "Transformation Matrices' on p207.

Comment: @user1412469 have you found the solution to find coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process *all* the text operators, you also need to know how some of them work. For instance a vertical writing font will apply the W2 entries to move the horizontal glyph origin to the vertical glyph origin before drawing glyphs.

In addition to Tm, TD and Td you need to handle T*, in addition to TJ and Tj you need to handle '  and " If you want to know how text is positioned within a single 'show' operation then you also need to consider the values of Tc, Tw, Tz, TL and Ts.

You may also need to handle the Current Transformation Matrix.

Comment: I already have methods to handle the T*, ', ", Tc, Tw, TL, and Ts (I'll have to research about Tz). So you mean I have to use ALL of them?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want exact text placement, then yes, all of them, and the CTM, and possibly some of the more outlandish stuff such as the W2 font metrics, in short everything which has a bearing on the placement of glyphs.

Comment: alright then! Just want more question. How will I correlate all the info I'll gather to find the text placement? I mean how will I relate the Tm values or Td/TD values to other values? That's what's bugging me right now.

Comment: To find the initial origin you multiply the Text Matrix by the Current Transformation Matrix. The resulting matrix Tx and Ty values are your origin. You then need to keep track of the text position as glyphs are drawn. If the font has a Widths array you can use that to calculate the current point after each glyph. Certain text state values will alter the width of glyphs, so be careful here (eg Tc and Tw). TD moves the currentpoint by Tx and Ty, Td does the same but uses unscaled text units. T* is similar but uses the value of leading in the text state as the Ty value. And so on....

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I just encountered another problem. Some pages of my pdf doesn't seem to have Td or TD operators. It doesn't register any callbacks so I assumed that it doesn't user those said operators at all. Will this be a problem for me?

Comment: Not really, its entirely possible not to use those operators, instead the PDF can position the lines of text individually. In fact I would say this is by far the more common usage and TD or Td much less used. Its just that in the general case you have to cater for all the possibilities.

Comment: Ah that explains it! Thank you very much for your help! :D